# Rails MSSQL connetion - TinyTds::Error: closed connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, tiny-tds

I'm currently trying to setup a Redmine installation for our team. I can't seem to establish a connection to our MSSQL server from within rails.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
TinyTds::Error: closed connection
/home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I installed sqlcmd to test the connection outside out rails, and I managed to login and create and drop a table as a test. I suspect it's my database.yml. I have to connect to an MS SQL Instance, and the server in running on a different port. Tried to tweak around with the settings a bit, but couldn't get it working.

database.yml

```
production:
adapter: sqlserver
database: Redmine01
dataserver: server\instance
port: ####
username: user
password: "password"
encoding: utf8mb4
```

While I've played around with rails a bit before, my rails knowledge is definitely limited and I've never set up a connection to an MS SQL server or used the TinyTds gem, therefore I suspect that I simply didn't configure my environment correctly. Hence my post here. I'd really appreciate if one of you rails experts could take a look at the database config. The information I could find regarding configuring rails to connect to named instance combined with a non-standard SQL port were limited.

As a sidenote, for sqlcmd I used "-S server\instance,####" to establish the connection. Which I've surely tried in the database.yml too, but without any success.

Comment: The amount of help we can give you debugging a database connection is really limited. There are just way to many unknowns.

Comment: Happy to provide any further information that could help. Knowing if my database.yml is set up corrently would also be a good input, since I'd know that I have to look further and didn't just incorrectly define instance and port within the .yml file (shown above)

Comment: There is no way we can know if your database.yml is setup properly without knowing the exact configuration of the database you are connecting to which is something you can't really share with us.

Comment: I'm aware that there are a lot of variables involved, which is why I tested the connection outside of rails, to ensure it isn't a network issue. Any push into the right direction would be highly appreciated, not looking for a spoon-fed solution here. I'm really just lost as to where to look further, since the format of the database.yml is what I found to be correct for a MS SQL connection. Are there any other paramaters in the database.yml that I should be aware of that I have left out? Is there a way to get a more detailed message by TinyTds than "closed connection"?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, leaving out the instance does the job.

```
production:
adapter: sqlserver
database: Redmine01
dataserver: server
port: ####
username: user
password: "password"
```